# iteration through an array and then calling .reduce on an array with promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I know this is probably a very basic question, but I am just learning and am stuck. I can't wrap my mind around how to do what I need to do here.

I have this array called RallyResults

```js
rallyResults [ { ExecutionType: 'ci',
    dataArray:
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object] ] },
    { ExecutionType: 'regression',
    dataArray: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
     { ExecutionType: 'ci',
    dataArray: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }
  { ExecutionType: 'regression',
    dataArray: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

I need to iterate through the rallyResults array and when the rallyResults.ExecutionType is "Regression", I need to iterate through the rallyResults.dataArray, and do some processing on each item within the rallyResults.dataArray.  I only want to return when all the items in the rallyResults.dataArray have been processed.

I have tried several different iterations for the code without success.  This is what I have coded now.

```js
ProcessDatabase.prototype.ckForAddToSet = function (rallyResults) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var module = this;
        console.log('In ckForAddToSet')
        //console.log('rallyResults', rallyResults);


        rallyResults.forEach(function (entry) {
            //console.log('in ckForAddToSetentry', entry);
            if (entry.ExecutionType == 'regresstion' || entry.ExecutionType 
                                               == 'smoke') {
                 entry.dataArray.reduce(function (p, val) {
                    return p.then(function () {
                        return module.addTestCaseToSet(val);
                    });
                }, Promise.resolve()).then(function (addResults) {
                    console.log('addResults ', addResults);
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log('error in reduce in ckForAddToSet', err);
                });
            }
        });
    })
}
```

It starts to iterate through the rallyResults and finds the first item where rallyResults.ExecutionType = 'regression', calls  entry.dataArray.reduce.

It processes all the dataArray records through the module.addTestCaseToSet method like I need it to and returns back and prints the console.log('addResults ', addResults); from the promise.resolve in the .reduce.

It then stops.

What I have not been able to figure out how to get it to continue to iterate through the remaining rallyResults items.  I did try to put a resolve when it returns from the module.addTestCaseToSet method in the .reduce, but that ends the entire process and still doesn't process all the rallyResult items.

Here is the addTestCaseToSet method

```js
ProcessDatabase.prototype.addTestCaseToSet = function (data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        console.log('in addTestCaseToSet', data);
        var dataValues = {
            data: [],
            tcvalues: []
        }
        dataValues.data = data;
        //console.log('dataValues.data', dataValues.data);
        rallyApi.getTestCase(dataValues.data.TestCaseId).then((values) => {

            dataValues.tcvalues = values;
            //console.log('dataValues = ',dataValues);
            resolve(dataValues);
        }, err => { reject('… failed finding testCase ' + dataValues.data.TestCaseId, err); });


    }).then(function (dataValues) {
        var module = this;
        var addToSet = [];
        const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            rallyApi.addTestCaseToSet(dataValues.tcvalues.ObjectID, dataValues.tcvalues.Ref, dataValues.data.TsObjectId, dataValues.data.TsRef).then((results) => {
                addToSet = results;
                resolve(addToSet);
            }, (err) => { reject(err); });
        });

        results.push(promise.then(() => {
            addResults.push(addToSet);
        },
            err => { console.log('… failed', err); throw err; }
        ));
        return Promise.all(results).then(() => addResults);

    })
}
```

The results from the module.addTestCaseToSet is below:

```js
addResults  [ { tsRef: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testset/203724645320',
    tcRef: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcase/152495978580',
    action: 'added' },
  { tsRef: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testset/203724645320',
    tcRef: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcase/192221079432',
    action: 'added' },
  { tsRef: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testset/203724645320',
    tcRef: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcase/128260769452',
    action: 'added' }]
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `module.addTestCaseToSet()` return?

Comment: I have added what is returned from the module.addTestCaseToSet in the initial post.  It was to long to put here.

Comment: I really just want to know whether or not `module.addTestCaseToSet(val);` returns <Promise>.

Comment: Oh ok.  I think it does.  I say I think because that was my intention.  But because I am really new to this.  It may not be coded correctly.  I added that method in the initial post also.

Comment: OK, `ProcessDatabase.addTestCaseToSet()` certainly returns a promise, though the code should simplify considerably. Is there a particular reason you chose to make your calls to that method serially (with the `.reduce()` pattern)? If those calls can be made in parallel, then the code will simplify further.

Comment: It is actually interacting with another application (CA Rall)y and adding testcases to the same testset.  Doing that in parallel will result in conflicts and will fail.

Comment: OK, I think I understand enough now to be able to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `ProcessDatabase.addTestCaseToSet()` nor `ProcessDatabase.ckForAddToSet()` needs an explicit `new Promise()`. There's plenty of opportunity to return naturally occuring promises.

`ProcessDatabase.addTestCaseToSet()` looks to be overcomplicated and is rather confusing in the area of `addToSet`/`addResults`/`results`.

At its simplest, `ProcessDatabase.addTestCaseToSet()` might be written as follows :

```
ProcessDatabase.prototype.addTestCaseToSet = function(data) {
    return rallyApi.getTestCase(data.TestCaseId)
    .then(values => rallyApi.addTestCaseToSet(values.ObjectID, values.Ref, data.TsObjectId, data.TsRef))
    .catch(err => {
        throw new Error('… failed adding testCase ' + data.TestCaseId + ' (' + err.message + ')');
    });
};
```

In this rewrite of `ProcessDatabase.addTestCaseToSet()`, the following assumptions are made :

- `rallyApi.addTestCaseToSet()` returns either results or promise of results (not an array of promises).
- no side effects are necessary and delivery of results via the returned promise meets the function's requirement.

In `ProcessDatabase.ckForAddToSet()` the pattern `rallyResults.forEach(function(entry) => { ...; entry.dataArray.reduce(...) });` only partially meets the objective of calling `module.addTestCaseToSet(data)` serially. To fully meet that objective, the outer loop (`.forEach()`) needs to be replaced with the same `.reduce()` pattern used for the inner loop.

Try something like this :

```
ProcessDatabase.prototype.ckForAddToSet = function(rallyResults) {
    var module = this;
    return rallyResults
    .filter(entry => entry.ExecutionType === 'regression' || entry.ExecutionType == 'smoke')
    .map(entry => entry.dataArray)
    .reduce((promise0, dataArray) => {
        return promise0.then(arr0 => {
            return dataArray.reduce((promise1, data) => {
                return promise1.then(arr1) => {
                    return module.addTestCaseToSet(data)
                    .then(result1 => {
                        arr1.push(result1);
                        return arr1;
                    });
                });
            }, Promise.resolve([]))
            .then(result0 => {
                arr0.push(result0);
                return arr0;
            });
        });
    }, Promise.resolve([]))
    .then(addResults => {
        console.log('addResults ', addResults); // addResults will be an array of arrays.
    }, err => {
        console.log('error in reduce in ckForAddToSet', err);
    });
};
```

There's probably still some work to do, but that should be much closer to what you want.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Roamer!.  This is definitely a much cleaner implementation

Comment: No worries Christine. I hope it serves you well. Out of interest, how close did I get to something that actually works?